# listview select item backcolor

Tags: c#, listview, select, listitem

Do I programmatically have to manage the backcolor\highlight color on a Listview's item when selected through code?

So if I do this: `listView1.Items[1].Selected = true;`

Do I also need to do this, so it looks highlight, as it does when selected with a mouse click: `listView1.Items[1].BackColor = Color.Blue;`

(and clear it when the selection changes)

I would have thought that Selected = true would also do the 'backcolor\highlighting' that happens through the mouse click.   Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the control got focus? If not the default setting is to hide the selection when the control doesn't have focus - see the HideSelection property.

Comment: Does setting the HideSelection=False and then giving a diff control focus keep the item's background as blue or is it that beige color (which I can barely see on my monitor)?

Comment: Removing focus from the listview changes the selection to a beige color on my Windows 7 machine - it is difficult to see I must admit.

If you want to keep the selection blue you'll need to manually manage the selection state and set the background colour of the item.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to handle the highlighting code yourself, but the item will only appear highlighted if the `ListView` control has focus.  Add `listView1.Select()` after you select the item and see if that helps.

Otherwise, you'll need to set the `HideSelection` property on the `ListView` to `false`.